# dropDownBox not getting the binded Value

Tags: c#

i have this code :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Type" runat="server" Enabled="false"  DataValueField="TERMINAL_TYPE_NAME" DataTextField="TERMINAL_TYPE_NAME"></asp:DropDownList>
```

the TERMINAL_TYPE_NAME is a column inside dataTable that is declared from the server side and it's contains only one value what should i do to give that dropDownlist the value return from the dataTable because the above code is displaying nothing in the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should

1. set the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) accordingly to your `DataTable` (!)
2. set the [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) (what is displayed)
3. set the [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) (what is the key field)
4. [`DataBind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.databind.aspx) the `DropDownList`  (!)

So for example in `Page_Load`:

```
if(!IsPostBack) 
{
    DdlType.DataSource = getYourDataTable();
    DdlType.DataValueField = "TERMINAL_TYPE_NAME";
    DdlType.DataTextField  = "TERMINAL_TYPE_NAME";
    DdlType.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: can you please provide for me an example ?

Comment: i just did that but nothing happend

Comment: @bassem: Have you debugged to inspect the DataTable. Can you show more code?

Comment: Check if data is there in the fetched DataTable

Comment: thank you it wored :) but i have a question as well my dataTable contains alot of data lots of columns and rows when i give the dataTable to the dropdownlist does that has a speed problem when talking about the server  ? like getting the data over and over again if we say that we have multiple dropdownlist ??

Comment: @bassem: You should select only that columns that you need(don't use `*`). You should not databind the DropDownList on every postback, by default ViewState is enabled, therefore it is unnecessary to load the data over and over again. If you need this data often and it doesn't change, you can consider to store it in Session or Cache (e.g. if it's master data).